# Convert roman to words/number in Perl

Tags: perl, roman-numerals

I have an input from a file, and I need to convert the roman numerals in the input to words or integers. 
In my article there are combination of strings, numbers, roman numbers, but i need only to change the roman to number, i used convert::number::roman but it takes whole text and of course its not roman

When I use roman, it should convert the value we put in:

```
 $roman = roman(13);                        
 $arabic = arabic($roman) if isroman($roman);
```

Please advise me?

Comment: The first question should always be: "Is there a module on CPAN that will do the job?"  You go to http://search.cpan.org/ to find out.  A search for 'Roman' reveals the module [`Roman`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Roman) for starters; and [`Math::Roman`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3A%3ARoman), and [`Text::Roman`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ARoman), and [`Convert::Number::Roman`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Convert%3A%3ANumber%3A%3ARoman).

Comment: i knew there are cpan. still trying

Comment: because in my article there are also strings, but i need only to change the roman to number, i used convert::number::roman but it takes whole text and of course its not roman

Comment: If you've tried such modules, you should say so in the question, explaining what the issues are.  That would improve your question enormously, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you are trying to convert roman numerals contained inside a larger text. The simplest way to do this, though rather brute-force, would be to do an eval substitution. For example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Roman 'roman2int';

my $text = <<'END';
Tim: Let's meet at half past VI.
Toady: Hmm, no good. How about quarter to IX?
END

$text =~ s/\b(\w+)\b/roman2int($1) || $1/ge;

print $text;
```

Since `roman2int` returns undef on failure to convert, we simply try to convert each word and if it succeeds use it else leave the original word. This of course will have problems, like words that are valid roman numerals, like `I`, `IV`, `ID`, `DIM`, etc etc. This is of course, up to you.

On a related note, it might be fun to run the code over a dictionary and see how many words are valid roman numerals :-)

Comment: `$text =~ s/Tim/Brutus/; $text =~ s/Toady/Julius/`

Comment: i got it, but is there any line roman2text? as i also want to change to words

Comment: @new: You could write your own `roman2text`, just ensure it returns `undef` early if that's what `roman2int` returns. Then you would have an integer in your sub-routine and could use any other CPAN module to convert it further.